# Twitter API 1.1 to fetch tweets list

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth

For my CMS component I'm implementing integration with Twitter API to fetch and display list of tweets (either connected to user or search query). I'm using [Twitter Restful API v1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1), since the 1.0 version is going to be dropped in [two months](https://twitter.com/SteveStreza/status/243448710497976320). Two interesting requests for me are [user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) and [search](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) one.

Since my technology strongly relies on caching I need to avoid server-side processing as much as possible providing static html and piece of javascript. I've done it already for old version API and it worked fine. New approach however requires providing authentication data via OAuth. One of the property (`oath_signature`) is a hash of other properties (in which there are `oauth_timestamp` and `oath_nonce`, which should (should they?) be unique per each twitter request) and secret keys, thus make it unsecure to generate it on client side.

Is there any secure way to get list of tweets on client-side using new API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is, "no, there is no secure way of doing this without server-side code." What I would do is set up a service to poll Twitter every xxxx seconds and retrieve the desired tweets. You should cache or store the results and then empty them each time you make your next request. If you are using C#, I have been working on a [C# Twitter library](https://github.com/zkniebel/TweetNet) that replicates Twitter's API and already has support for grabbing a user's timeline. I will be adding support for filter and search within the next two days (each one should take no more than ten minutes to implement, excluding testing, if you decide to do it yourself). You can reference this library in the service that I mentioned before.

If you do not have the server resources that you need for this, then I strongly caution you against using solutions that circumvent Twitter's intended securities, as it could leave you or your client in a vulnerable position.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write a proxy web service on your server side. And as you say caching will be critical to avoid the 15 requests per 15 minutes for basic stuff like pulling tweets.

Definitely avoid doing any auth stuff on the front end. The new "[application only](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth)" auth using OAuth 2 would allow you to embed bearer tokens in JavaScript meaning you don't need to do any of the signature stuff you're talking about. But don't. Anyone could use your bearer token and if your own users didn't exhaust the rate limit, other people stealing your token might.

If you don't have the server side resources to do this yoursefl, you might want to look at [Flamingo](http://twproxy.eu/).  It'll do the auth and the caching for you, so you only need to work in JS like you used to.